# Botón Atrás con 3 layouts en Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xml

Mi app tiene un layout A que es un Login, el layout B es un menu principal que tiene un boton que te envia al layout C, Existe un boton Salir que me permite pasar del B al A, pero cuando intento retroceder del C al B me da error y me regresa al A.

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--Add Other activities like this-->
    <activity
        android:name = ".PanelPrincipal"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name = "android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value = ".LoginActivity"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PanelPrincipal" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name = ".ActivityC"
        android:parentActivityName=".PanelPrincipal">
        <meta-data
            android:name = "android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value = ".PanelPrincipal"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ActivityC" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola el problema no está en tu Manifest, sino en la forma en que inicias una actividad, si quieres que no te pase, borra el finish(); que tienes en tu activity B, tiene que ser ese el problema.

Comment: No he usado finish() en ningun activity